# How Int is specified in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I looked at the **Int** implementation in Alloy (i.e., `integer.als` file in the util directory ) and I come up with the following expressions (aside many others) which I could not understand:

> fun add  [n1, n2: Int] : Int { this/plus[n1, n2] }
>
> fun plus [n1, n2: Int] : Int { n1 fun/add n2 }

**I have two questions:**

1) What do the body of these functions mean? ( it seems one calls another! Can anybody please explain how come this implement add!?)

2) Is there any axiomatic definition for the finite Integers (i.e., Int) in Alloy?

I was looking to see if there is any set of axioms which defines **Int** as a finite subset of natural numbers, i.e.,  0 =< Int <= Max. Is there such a thing in Alloy, or it is just using common integers under the hood of these seemingly fake functions .( By the latter statement, I assume the function bodies are fake and this might partly answer my first question!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `this/plus` just "calls" the `plus` function defined in the same file (`integer.als`); `fun/add`, on the other hand, calls the built-in `add` function, which is part of the Alloy implementation, and cannot be defined as a library.  The built-in `add` function implements binary addition of two integers represented in a two's complement, which cannot be done at the Alloy language level.
2. there is no axiomatic definition of integers in Alloy.  Alloy explicitly enumerates all integers within a bitwidth and adds them to the Alloy universe (along with all other atoms)

Answer (score 1):

To find the max int, you should search for bitwidth. When you specify the Int scope in a run statement, you specify the bitwidth. For example, if you specify

```
run{} for 3 Int
```

You will get integers as big as 3 and as small as -4.
The general rule is (2^x-1)-1 for positive numbers and (2^x-1) for negative numbers where X is the scope for Int.

I guess the libs in util/integer are helpers to deal with the tricky Int semantics in Alloy